# CSS grid row flexibility issue

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I understand why this isn't working, but I can't think of an alternative. Is there any way to have each column's rows span the height of it's content different than the other column rows?

What's pasted below works exactly how I need it to, but it isn't correct. `.recent` is starting on row 2, and spanning 2 rows, making the total number of rows 4. This creates a huge gap below `.middle` and `.right`. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of CSS grid]

@dwjohnston screenshot of grid with your solution:

[image: Screenshot of grid with your solution]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: start;
  background: pink;
}

.grid>.left {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: green;
}

.grid>.recent {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  background: red;
}

.grid>.middle {
  grid-column: 4 / span 5;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: gray;
}

.grid>.right {
  grid-column: 9 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="recent">
    Recent
    <br> Testing
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Middle
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "What's pasted below works exactly how I need it to, but it isn't correct."

What does this mean? Is what you have here what you want or not? I an't see the gap you are referring to.

Comment: The pink below the gray is the 4th row created by `.recent`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand the problem correctly, I think I see the problem.

Here's my solution:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: start;
  background: pink;
}

.grid>.left {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: green;
}

.grid>.recent {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  background: red;
}

.grid>.middle {
  grid-column: 4 / span 5;
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  background: gray;
}

.grid>.right {
  grid-column: 9 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="recent">
    Recent
    <br> Testing
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Middle
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
    <br>text<br>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

What you were doing in your answer was:

- `.left`. takes row 1,
- `.recent` takes rows 2 and 3, this creates a
  third row at the bottom, including the 20px gap.
- `.middle` takes row
  1 & 2, but is really big, so it pushes row 2 out and makes it
  massive.

What I've done is made `.middle` span 4, so it takes rows 1,2,3,4. This lets `.recent` have its own small sized rows, and gives `.middle` the forth row (by default all the rows are sized auto) take up as much space as it wants to grow into.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've tried this as well. With this it creates a gap between green (left) and red (recent).

Comment: That gap is the grid gap.

Comment: Negative. Not only is there a gap, the columns no longer act like I need them to. I updated my question with a screenshot of your solution.

Comment: @johndoe - I updated my solution with a screenshot - I'm not sure what's going on with your screenshot.

Comment: It's highlighting the grid.

Comment: This works perfect, until `.right` is pushed down beyond `.recent`.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what u are looking for, as per the below comments to me and others, you can see it's without any gaps, hope it helps :)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 20px 20px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 30% auto 30%;
}
.grid > .left {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: green;
}
.grid > .recent {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: red;
}
.grid > .middle {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: gray;
  height: 100vh;
}
.grid > .right {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="recent">
    Recent Testing
  </div>
  <div class="middle">Middle
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When `.middle` is pushed down, it takes `.left` with it. Each row in each column needs to act independently. Honestly, I don't think this is possible with CSS's grid.

Comment: please have a look at the second snippet, as an example for "each column needs to act independently", in this way `green`, `red` and `brown` columns are independent of height variation

Comment: The problem with that is, I lose the ability to order the rows when on a handheld device. When the device width is less than 576, the order needs to be: left, middle, recent, right stacked on top of each other :/

Comment: @johndoe, please have a look at the above snippet, based on all comments it can be achieved as shown above :)